# "Cannot Serialize Multidimensional Arrays" -What is it, and what did I type wrong?

Tags: c#, xml, xna

I've been trying to Import XML files into my XNA project for quite a while.
Just when I thought that I'd gotten it all done, this error pops up. Lots of searching, and I haven't found an answer that helps.
This is a clipped version of my XML document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<XnaContent>
  <!-- TODO: replace this Asset with your own XML asset data. -->
  <Asset Type="Library.Room">
    <Tile itIs="Wall">
      <x>0</x>
      <y>0</y>
      <o>0</o>
    </Tile>
  </Asset>
</XnaContent>
```

When trying to Build, I get this Error:

"Building content threw RankException: Cannot serialize multidimensional arrays."

Even commenting out lines of my project code do nothing to change this error, so I know that it's something in how I've written my XML. ( Which I thought was okay )

So, that tells me that I'm probably writing my XML wrong. What is a MultiDimensional Array in XML, and how can I avoid it?

___Added Info

I add the XML info to an Array here, piece by piece. --naturally, I thought that this was the problem at first, but commenting any of this out has no effect.

```
        public void loadFromFile(string fileName, Room r)
        {
            var doc = XElement.Load(fileName);
            foreach (var v in roomDoc.Elements("Tile"))
            {
                r.blueprint.SetValue(new Things.Wall((int)v.Element("o")), (int)v.Element("x"), (int)v.Element("y"));
            }
        }
```

Comment: how are you parsing the arrays?

Comment: also, if you were to build a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/), except with your 'clipped' XML, do you encounter the same problem?

Comment: Check out [this question](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/50297/loading-levels-in-xna-from-xml) as I think you will find it useful. If you want to load XML from the file system I recommend checking out my answer. If you want to use the content pipeline then definitely check out the intermediate serializer. Using the intermediate serializer you can create an object in code and export it as XML to see what your XML should actually look like for importing into XNA via the content pipeline. Very cool stuff.